# How do you change the border dimensions of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Given the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox} foobar \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How would one change the bordersizes indicated in red?

Comment: What about taking a look a [tcolorbox](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox) documentation? Section 4.7.4 Spacing explains what you need. You can also find it in your system through command  "texdoc tcolorbox".

Comment: Thanks, I did skim through the manual but didn't find that section and didn't find easy Google-able results. I eventually did find it in one of the example (after I already asked here). At least now this question is Google-able.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the spaces with the keys `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`.

Meaning you can do either `\tcbset{top=1mm,left=1mm}` or give the keys directly to the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[left=1mm,top=1mm] foobar \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput]

There is also the key `boxsep` which *adds* space to the `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` and `middle` where appropriate. The initial value for this key is `1mm`, meaning that if you want the top margin to be exactly `1mm`, the sum of `top` and `boxsep` should be `1mm` and so on. Thus, in the above example, both the top and left margins are `2mm` in total.